# Pairwise independence implies X+Y is independent from Z

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, independence

Let $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ be three pairwise independent random variables.

1. Is it true that $(X, Y)$ is independent from $Z$?
2. Is it true that
   $X+Y$ is independent from $Z$?

I know that this holds for mutually independent random variables but can't prove it for the pairwise independent case.

Comment: (1) intuitively should not be - what are your thoughts?

Answer (score 7):

Consider e.g. $(X,Y,Z)$ uniform over $\{(0,0,0),(0,1,1),(1,0,1),(1,1,0)\}$. We can easily see that $(X,Y,Z)$ are pairwise independent.

But knowing $(X,Y)$ or $X+Y$ immediately determines the value of $Z$.

---

Some motivation for this example: $X$, $Y$ are independent coin flips, and $Z=X\oplus Y$ is XOR. Knowing one of the bits doesn't affect the distribution of any one of the other bits. But knowing two of the bits actually determines the value of the other bit.